# Deciding Countability of Languages

Tags: formal-languages, uncountability

Suppose we have given $\Sigma=\{a,b\}$, Which one of the following set is not countable

> (a) Set of all languages over $\Sigma$
>
> (b) Set of all regular languages over $\Sigma$
>
> (c) Set of all languages over $\Sigma$ accepted by Turing machine

I've read some techniques to find answer to the question like whether

> Is the set of all infinite sequences of some alphabets countable or not
>
> Is the set of all finite non-empty subsets of some alphabets countable or not

But they didn't helped me to answer questions like above. I tried `Cantor Diagonalization` but it didn't help either. How can we answer such questions.

Comment: Hint: is the set of all Turing machines countable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (a) Un-Countable
>
> (b) Countable
>
> Regular Language may be finite or infinite. Either case enumeration is possible as it contains pattern. Hence, Set of all regular languages over $\sum$ are Countable.
>
> (c) Countable
>
> Since Language accepted by Turing Machine is `Recursively Enumerable languages`, As Enumeration is possible. Hence, Set of all languages over $\sum$ accepted by TM are Countable

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding your reasoning.

Comment: For (b), your reasoning is insufficient as is. HINT: think about (c).